# MySQL get result from multiplying cells in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, multiplication

I am trying to get a proper query to no luck.
Here is the picture.

- In table "products" I have the following fields `ID, PRICESELL, TAXCATEG`
- In table "TAXCATEG". I have the following fields, `ID, TAXVALUE`

I need to get the sum by multiplying the "`pricesell`" on the tax value.
I.e `pricsell_withtax` (this column is not in the table anywhere) = 3 euro + 18% (in TAXVALUE, the value is stored as 18) = 3.54

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a simple `JOIN` query. Just join the two tables on `ID` and select `pricesell * (1 + taxvalue/100)`,

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `taxcateg` field on the `products` table is matches the `id` field on the `taxcateg` table.

If so, something like this should do the job.

```
select
   p.*,
   t.*,
   p.pricesell + (p.pricesell * t.taxvalue)/100 as pricesell_withtax
from
   products p
   JOIN taxcateg t ON 
      p.taxcateg = t.id;
```